# How to run a docker container in azure devops?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

I'm currently playing around with docker containers and azure devops with the goal to run a couple of tests from it.

This is what I currently do:

1. I have created a dockerfile in my repo
2. I have created a pipline that build and push an image to container registry
3. I have checked that the image exist in container registry
4. I have started on a new release pipline with the following task:

   - A login task:

     ```
      steps:
       - task: Docker@2
         displayName: Login
         inputs:
           containerRegistry: nameOfMyRegistry
           command: login
     ```
   - A run task:

     ```
     steps:
        - task: Docker@2
          displayName: 'Run tests'
          inputs:
             containerRegistry: nameOfRegistry
             repository: nameOfRepository
             command: run
             arguments: 'nameOfImage -p 8089:8089 -f tests.py --run-time 30s -u 1 -r 1'
     ```

But after I run this I get the following error:

```
            2021-04-26T11:39:38.9204965Z ##[error]Unable to find image 'nameOfMyImage:latest' locally

            2021-04-26T11:39:38.9228444Z ##[error]docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for nameOfMyImage:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest tagged by "latest" is not found.
```

So I'm not sure if I'm missing something? I put in all information to my azure container registry so I thought it would just get the image from it but it seems like it can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know I got answer that say you can't use `run` with the `Docker@2` task but I actually managed to get it to run now. The problem was that I used the wrong name of the image. I had to write it like this:

`nameOfRegistry.azurecr.io/nameOfRepository:tag`

So just bad from me but I will leave this here if someone manage to do the same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing complex, looks like task input `command` supports only `buildAndPush`, `build`, `push`, `login`, `logout` and it doesn't support `run` [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#task-inputs)

Something like this with `script` should work. [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#startstop)

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: builder
    image: ubuntu:18.04
steps:
- script: echo "I can run inside the container (it starts by default)"
  target:
    container: builder
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no option `run` in specification

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#task-inputs

To build an application and run tests right after the build you can use following commands:

```
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Login to ACR
  inputs:
    command: login
    containerRegistry: dockerRegistryServiceConnection1
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: build
    repository: contosoRepository
    tags: tag1
```

If you want to run tests in Docker container, you should use

- Container Structure Tests
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/container-structure-test-task?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml
- Azure Container Instances https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanielMeixner.de-danielmeixner-anycode&targetId=5467da56-2ffa-43cd-87b7-0b2c6da5b5af

Comment: Actually, you can put whatever docker command you want in the `command`-variable. The ones listed are just the ones with specific implementations. All other values will use the `dockercommand`-handler.



[Source code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/6f2429cb09b4ed3c41adbfd62c9d74cca9263932/Tasks/DockerV2/docker.ts#L45-L48)